# How to select values in Postgresql that don't match json type?

Tags: postgresql

I have column "ЕИУ" that's text column. Some rows contains json values, but some can be NULL on not json(text for example.) I would like to extract all values that NOT json values.

[image]

[image]

None json values example

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables. And please add some of the "non-JSON"" data that you have when you **[edit]** your question because I can't see any evidence of that in your screen shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your sample data, you can simply get this using `NOT LIKE`

```
select * from your_table where column_name not like '{%}'
```

Otherwise, you can create a function that will try casting to `JSON` and return `true` or `false` based on that output.

```
select * from your_table where your_json_function(your_column);
```

Comment: Then you can [check this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=500ea18674a8994afe478e5a449c5b8a) @AlexNikitin